# VBA Write All Sub Folders To Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write out all folders, sub folders and sub folders etc of the main folder. I am not interested in files.

I have the code working if I just use messagebox... but when I try to write to sheet it just overwrites the previous line.

```
Sub sample()
   Dim FileSystem As Object
   Dim HostFolder As String
    
   HostFolder = "G:\"

   Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

   DoFolder FileSystem.getfolder(HostFolder)    
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(folder)
   Dim ln As Integer
   Dim subfolder       

   ln = 2    
   For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders    
      'MsgBox subfolder           
       DoFolder subfolder   
       ln = ln + 1
       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ln).Value = subfolder   
   Next

   'Dim file

   'For Each file In folder.files

   'MsgBox file

   'Next  
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
   Call sample 
   MsgBox ("complete")  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read the descriptions for tags before applying them. The VBA tag description states *"VBA is not equivalent to VB.NET"*. The VB.NET tag description states *"DO NOT USE this tag for VB6, VBA or VBScript questions"*. People watch specific tags because they are interested in questions relevant to them. If you add irrelevant tags, you waste our time by making us open irrelevant questions. Don't waste the time of strangers whom you would like to help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out... noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple.
That's because you defined the variable "ln" as a local variable inside the Sub "DoFolder".
You need to define the variable "ln" as a global variable.
Then, it will work well.
Most of your code is correct.

```
Public ln As Integer ' Define as a global

Sub sample()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    
    HostFolder = "G:\"
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
    ln = 2 ' Initialize here.

    DoFolder FileSystem.getfolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(folder)
    Dim subfolder
    'Dim ln As Integer
    'ln = 2

    For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders
        DoFolder subfolder
        ln = ln + 1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ln).Value = subfolder
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call sample
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, something so obvious.